# date('c') only being saved as data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, php-7

The date is being truncated or not used to update my MySQL table.

Generating the date in PHP 7:

```
$date = date('c');
$modelImportState->setImportCompletedTime($date);

try {
  $modelImportState->save();
  return true;
}
catch(\Exception $e){
    ....
}
```

This generates the data and time correctly but in the DM only the time is saved (field is DATETIME).

[image: Image of date with no time]

[image: Table structure]

Update:

The $modelImportState is a model from the Magento Framework (sorry, as the saving is working I thought that wasn't relevant). It is now fixed, it was because for some reason the column wasn't actually updated to Datetime when I changed it before.

Comment: What is `modelImportState`? And what is the code for the function `setImportCompletedTime`. Please provide complete sample code.

Comment: So what is saved in the DM? Time or date? Because on your image its shown correct date, and zeroed time... But you wrote only the time is saved.

Comment: It was because the time was zeroed out. See update, now fixed

Comment: Still not clear. @legionar is right. The value you show has a date and zero time. But you say only time is saved. Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

try this
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');